# IE Addin with WebServices under Vista

Tags: windows, wcf, service, windows-vista

I have an application that uses Add In Express (a product which creates Internet Explorer Add ons) and it consumes Web Services from within the browser.  It works great under XP however - due to I am guessing Vista security it breaks down. I reference http://www.add-in-express.com/forum/read.php?FID=5&TID=3948&MID=18878&phrase_id=1622760#message18878

I am thinking that to solve this I would need to create a windows service and then roll my own messaging back and forth between that service to actually consume the webservice. After reading about WCF I was wondering if could I use WCF using Self Hosting to consume the Web Services.  Would Vista allow that or would the security prohibit this as well?

Thanks
Mark

Answer (score 0):

You probably should take some of the information from that link and edit it into your question, so we don't all have to go clicking that link to find out what the problem is.